# Fade a Div to Visible/Hidden when other Divs are clicked

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, opacity

How would I make a Div change between being hidden or visible when one of three other Divs are clicked.

For example,

**CSS**

```
#red_box {
 position:absolute;
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 margin-top:50px;
 margin-left:50px;
 background-color:red;   
}

#green_box {
 position:absolute;
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 margin-top:150px;
 margin-left:150px;
 background-color:green;    
}

#yellow_box {
 position:absolute;
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 margin-top:50px;
 margin-left:150px;
 background-color:yellow;    
}

#blue_box {
 position:absolute;
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 margin-top:150px;
 margin-left:50px;
 background-color:blue;    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="red_box"></div>
<div id="yellow_box"></div>
<div id="green_box"></div>
<div id="blue_box"></div>
```

I'm looking to toggle the visibility of the red box when any of the others are clicked. So, for example, if the user clicked the yellow box, the red box would vanish and then if they clicked the green box it would reappear. However I need it so they could click these boxes in any order and everytime they click one, it would either make the red box visible or hide it, depending on whether or not it is already hidden or visible.

I hope this is making sense.

I am also curious about how I would do this with a fade effect, so instead of the red box just vanishing or appearing, it would slowly fade in or out.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96TsV/1/) of the code above.

I'm unsure as whether this can be achieved solely through CSS or whether it could/should be done with JQuery. I'm also unsure as whether it would use opacities or the display:none; tag, or neither, or both.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It can be achieved through CSS3, note the limit on browser compatibility, although you would still want to use a couple of lines of straight javascript. (Style the transition with CSS, trigger the transition with onclick javascript.) If you are going to include the jquery library for any other reason then you may as well use it - apparently people still use IE8... if you wouldn't otherwise include jquery then don't bog down your site, just sacrifice the eye candy for the n00b browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below jquery

add some class in other three div's(yellow,green,blue) then

```
$('.some').click(function(){
    $("#red_box").fadeToggle();
});
```

so you html will be

```
<div id="red_box"></div>
<div id="yellow_box" class="some"></div>
<div id="green_box" class="some"></div>
<div id="blue_box" class="some"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I've understood you correctly, you want to fade in/fade out the red box whenever any of the other boxes are clicked. If that's right, you can use [`fadeToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/):

```
$("div").not("#red_box").click(function() {
    $("#red_box").fadeToggle();
});
```

Here's an [update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96TsV/2/).

If you don't care about the fade, you can use the normal [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method instead.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe:

```
$("div").on('click', function() {
    if (this.id != "red_box") {
        $('#red_box').fadeToggle(200);
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/96TsV/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't -- to my knowledge -- fade anything using only CSS. User interaction is also quite limited (`:hover` and `:focus`). You'll need Javascript.

The good news is that it is really simple. Just add a class to the divs which should toggle the red box, and add the following Javascript to make them toggle it: http://jsfiddle.net/J2uzU/

```
$('.togglesRed').click(function(){
    $('#red_box').fadeToggle();
});
```